# Android - Make app send heartbeat to server

Tags: java, android, http, android-service

I need to implement a regular `heartbeat`.

The `heartbeat` itself is a simple `HTTP-GET` call to my server.

The thing is I want to send it as long as my app is open. When I close the app the sending should stop.

I read a few things about [Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775628/android-how-to-periodically-send-location-to-a-server) and [AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377875/1331671) but how can I call/stop them when navigating through my app activities?

[This also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10207775/1331671) seems nice but still the same problem:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runable = new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        //do your code here
        //also call the same runnable 
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    finally{
        //also call the same runnable 
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}
};
handler.postDelayed(runable, 1000);
```

Could anybody maybe post a good example or a link?

Thanks!

Comment: You could always try a thread...or AsyncTask... or a service...

Comment: Just use a TimerTask which sends this command every say second and then override the method onStop() and onDestroy() and delete your TimerTask.

Comment: i updated my question to hopefully reduce the storm of bad votings :)

Comment: Once a second HTTP request will kill the battery. Reconsider this design.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev thanks for the input but its not for mobiles, so there is no battery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is I want to send it as long as my app is open. When I close
>   the app the sending should stop

In android a bit harder than in iOS, but lets do it:
In Android you don't have a callback at application level when the app it goes to background or is killed. Instead of thins you should handle at each Activity onStop Method for example. Take a look at Activity lifecycle:
[image]

or onDestroy method. Note:
When an activity it isn't visible anymore it can be because your app is gone to background, closed or other activity is visible. You have to decide which case is and use your HTTP Get / Post, or stop it , when needed.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884494/529543) is a sample code with Async task to send data over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a simple timeout using a similar `Handler` to your code. When an `Activity` calls `onPause` trigger the timeout on a 10 second delay, when an `Activity` calls `onResume` cancel that call with `removeRunnable(...)` if the timeout code fires you know the user has left your app (this is the reason for the 10 second timeout, to give a new `Activity` time to launch if there is one).

You could add something in your timeout code to kill the heartbeat. e.g. cancel the heartbeat `Runnable`